# Crash Debugging Win32 Application

Tags: debugging, crash, windbg, crash-dumps

I'm spending lot of time doing crash debugging of Win32 apps. One thing i'm very curious to know about is, How to find whether any address belongs to stack / heap or program code section. Is there any windbg/ollydbg plugin available for this purpose? Or I've to to it manually from memory map?
Ex:

```
0:000> r
eax=00930264 ebx=008e0000 ecx=41414592 edx=00930000 esi=41414141 edi=008e0441
eip=00407289 esp=0012fae0 ebp=0012faf4 iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na pe nc
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=0038  gs=0000             efl=00010206
MyApp+0x7289:
00407289 8b1437          mov     edx,dword ptr [edi+esi] ds:0023:41cf4582=????????
0:000> u eip
MyApp+0x7289:
00407289 8b1437          mov     edx,dword ptr [edi+esi]
0040728c 8b4c3704        mov     ecx,dword ptr [edi+esi+4]
00407290 57              push    edi
00407291 e89ae8ffff      call    MyApp+0x5b30 (00405b30)
00407296 897d14          mov     dword ptr [ebp+14h],edi
00407299 5f              pop     edi
0040729a 85c0            test    eax,eax
0040729c 741e            je      MyApp+0x72bc (004072bc)
```

In this case i wanna know which register pointing to which section (code/stack/heap )so that i can proceed further to the root cause.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
0:000> ?@esi+@edi
Evaluate expression: 36278408 = 02299088
0:000> !address 02299088
 ProcessParametrs 00311020 in range 00310000 00410000
 Environment 02294848 in range 02290000 02390000
    02290000 : 02290000 - 00100000
                    Type     00020000 MEM_PRIVATE
                    Protect  00000004 PAGE_READWRITE
                    State    00001000 MEM_COMMIT
                    Usage    RegionUsageHeap
                    Handle   00310000
```

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for your response, Exactly what I wanted. Thanks again..

Here in my case I am getting this..

0:001> ?@esi+@edi
Evaluate expression: -1860812479 = 91164141
0:001> !address 91164141

                                     
Failed to map Heaps (error 80004005)
Address 91164141 could not be mapped in any available regions

What could be the possible reason for that??

Thanks,

Comment: 91164141 is 0x91164141 so it's beyond 2G limit, which is illegal user address, the register value is corrupted, so esi+edi yields trash value. if you notice that esi=41414141, this is apparently not a normal offset, rather a string 'AAAA', so esi is holding bad value

Comment: BTW, it looks you did not configure symbol path correctly since pdb for MyApp was missing there. It's very challenging to debug without symbols